# Track if the users have read documents Sharepoint 2010 Document Center

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document, receipt, user-tracking

I want to track if the users have read sharepoint 2010 document center's documents, currently user infos are not stored in audit logs, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is the steps.

1- Create a class library.

2- Right click the library and add new item.

3- Select ASP.NET Module under Web node.

4- Add PreRequestHandlerExecute event handler inside Init.Here is my code.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)    
{
   context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += context_PreRequestHandlerExecute;
}
```

5-  Methods

```
    void context_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            var app = sender as HttpApplication;
            if (app != null)
            {
                string requesturl = app.Request.Url.ToString();
                string file = string.Empty;
                // if document opens in browser
                if (app.Request.QueryString["Source"] != null && app.Request.QueryString["id"] != null && app.Request.QueryString["Source"].StartsWith(documentSiteUrl))
                {
                    file = app.Request.QueryString["id"].Remove(0, app.Request.QueryString["id"].LastIndexOf('/'));
                    Worker(file);
                }
                // if document opened installed office apps or downloaded the document
                if (requesturl.StartsWith(SiteUrl))
                {
                    requesturl = requesturl.Remove(0, requesturl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                    Worker(requesturl);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void Worker(string requesturl)
    {

        #region ext control
        List<string> extList = new List<string>(Exts.Split(';'));
        bool result = false;
        foreach (string item in extList)
        {
            if (requesturl.EndsWith(item))
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        if ((!requesturl.Contains(".aspx")) && (!requesturl.EndsWith("/")) && result)
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

            String fileName = requesturl.Substring(requesturl.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            // Add log
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            AddReadInfo(web.CurrentUser, fileName, web);
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }

    private void AddReadInfo(SPUser sPUser, string fileName, SPWeb web)
    {

        #region Logging

            SPList logList = web.Lists.TryGetList("LogList");
            if (logList != null)
            {
                SPListItem item = logList.Items.Add();
                item["User"] = sPUser.Name;
                item["Document"] = fileName;
                item["Read"] = "Read";
                item.Update();

            }

        #endregion

    }
```

6- Don't forget signing the project.

7- Build Project.

8- Add dll to GAC and BIN folder under the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\ folder.

9- Open IIS Manager.

10- Find your site nod and select.

11- Open Modules.

12- Right click under modules page and select Add Managed Module option.

13- Give a name and select your module under dropdownlist.

14- IIS reset.

Answer (score 0):

It gets stored in audit logs.
Enable auditing for that particular document library and then get the details using the following code:

```
SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite
SPList doclib= oSPWeb.Lists["doclib"];
SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb()
SPListItemCollection doclibitems= doclib.Items; 
foreach (SPListItem odoclibItem in doclibitems)
                        { 
odoclibItem .Audit.AuditFlags = SPAuditMaskType.View;
                        //    odoclibItem .Audit.AuditFlags = SPAuditMaskType
                            SPAuditQuery oquery = new SPAuditQuery(oSPsite);
                            oquery.RestrictToListItem(odoclibItem );
                            odoclibItem .Audit.Update();                        
                            SPAuditEntryCollection oAuditEntryCollection =SPsite.Audit.GetEntries(oquery);
                            foreach (SPAuditEntry entry in oAuditEntryCollection)
                            {
     if (entry.Event == SPAuditEventType.View)
    {
    id = Convert.ToString(entry.UserId);
     // get the user name and other details here
     }
   }
       }
```

Comment: How to enable auditing for particular library? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I am sorry. it was Enabling auditing only for view items which  is also in the same code. Try using the above code.It might work